# Jscript to check defined array

Tags: jscript

My code gathers all categories from a CSV file, sorts and grabs top 10 categories and the top 10 result are displayed on a chart. The code works fine if the gategory found is 10, but if it is less than 10 no chart is displayed..basically code dies.

I am a newbie when it comes to coding and the code was passed on to me by someone else who is not available. What I would like to add is an if cases that checks:

- Gather all category, sort
  Set category to 1 to 10
- if category is null, stop. Chart has no value
- if category=1 ===> Display found value
- if category=2 ===> Display found value
- if category=3 ===> Display found value
- if category=3 ===> Display found value
- So on, so on..untill it reaches to 10

```
//collect top 10 cat from array
catArray.sort(sort_by("count", false, function (a) {
    return parseInt(a)
}));
var categorytop10 = new Array(catArray[0]["tier3"], catArray[1]["tier3"], catArray[2]["tier3"], catArray[3]["tier3"], catArray[4]["tier3"], catArray[5]["tier3"], catArray[6]["tier3"], catArray[7]["tier3"], catArray[8]["tier3"], catArray[9]["tier3"]);

var categorytop10Count = new Array(catArray[0]["count"], catArray[1]["count"], catArray[2]["count"], catArray[3]["count"], catArray[4]["count"], catArray[5]["count"], catArray[6]["count"], catArray[7]["count"], catArray[8]["count"], catArray[9]["count"]);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "The code works fine if the category found is 10, but if it is less than 10 no chart is displayed..basically code dies." Do you mean that the code dies, if there are LESS than 10 categories in the array? Does the catArray ever contain less than 10 categories?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I mean...if there are LESS than 10 categories in the array...no result is shown. The objective is to display top 10 category, but if there are less than 10, then it should display whatever that is available i.e 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9......Thank for the help

Comment: Yes, that's what the code in the answer I posted does. But since you did not provide the chart rendering code, we don't know what input that code is expecting. Will the chart rendering code work with arrays with less than 10 items? If not then that code would have to be modified as well. Anyway if the answer helped understand the issue better, please accept it.

Comment: I added another possible solution, see below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited info provided, here is what I can suggest.

```
//collect top 10 cat from array
catArray.sort(sort_by("count", false, function (a) {
    return parseInt(a)
}));

var categorytop10 = new Array();     
var categorytop10Count = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 10 && i < catArray.length; ++i)
{
    categorytop10.push( catArray[i]["tier3"] );
    categorytop10Count.push( catArray[i]["count"] );
}
```

EDIT: You can also try this

```
//collect top 10 cat from array
catArray.sort(sort_by("count", false, function (a) {
    return parseInt(a)
}));

var categorytop10 = new Array();     
var categorytop10Count = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if (i < catArray.length)
    {
        categorytop10.push( catArray[i]["tier3"] );
        categorytop10Count.push( catArray[i]["count"] );
    }
    else {
        categorytop10.push( "?" );
        categorytop10Count.push( "0" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much..so far it works...once all test are completed I will post again...Thank you again :)

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your original problem (not displaying in the chart) please accept the answer.